# Flatten directory structure and preserve duplicate files

Tags: bash, shell, unix, zsh

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
foo
├── 1.txt
├── 2.txt
├── 3.txt
├── 4.txt
└── bar
    ├── 1.txt
    ├── 2.txt
    └── 5.txt
```

I would like to flatten this directory structure so that all files are in the foo directory and duplicate files are preserved:

```
foo
├── 1.txt
├── 2.txt
├── 3.txt
├── 4.txt
├── bar-1.txt
├── bar-2.txt
└── bar-5.txt
```

The file names of the renamed duplicates is insignificant.

Is there a simple Unix one-liner or simple shell script I can use to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That should work:

```
target="/tmp/target"; find . -type f | while read line; do outbn="$(basename "$line")"; while true; do if [[ -e "$target/$outbn" ]]; then outbn="z-$outbn"; else break; fi; done; cp "$line" "$target/$outbn"; done
```

formatted as non-one-liner:

```
target="/tmp/target"
find . -type f | while read line; do
  outbn="$(basename "$line")"
  while true; do
    if [[ -e "$target/$outbn" ]]; then
      outbn="z-$outbn"
    else
      break
    fi
  done
  cp "$line" "$target/$outbn"
done
```

be sure to run that from the `foo` directory in you case and to set the `$target` variable to the target directory.

Example:

```
$ find foo
foo
foo/1
foo/2
foo/3
foo/4
foo/bar
foo/bar/1
foo/bar/2
foo/bar/3
foo/bar/4
foo/bar/5
```

```
$ cd foo/
$ target="/tmp/target"; find . -type f | while read line; do outbn="$(basename "$line")"; while true; do if [[ -e "$target/$outbn" ]]; then outbn="z-$outbn"; else break; fi; done; cp "$line" "$target/$outbn"; done
```

and then

```
$ find $target
/tmp/target
/tmp/target/1
/tmp/target/2
/tmp/target/3
/tmp/target/4
/tmp/target/5
/tmp/target/z-1
/tmp/target/z-2
/tmp/target/z-3
/tmp/target/z-4
```

Comment: basename - I have never come across this before, but definitely one to remember!

Answer (score 4):

I assume that I can rename `a/b/c.txt` to `a-b-c.txt` (ie: that it such a file doesn't exist in the top directory). Then you can:

```
 #copy all the files in the top directory
 for i in $(find . -type 'f' ); do
     cp $i $(echo $i | sed -e 's#./##' | tr / - );
 done

#remove subdirectories
find . -type 'd' | egrep -v "^.$" | xargs rm -r
```

Of course, you should backup your files before trying this kind of manipulations.

Comment: Better not to use command substitution in the for loop in this case, as it will fail when there is whitespace  in the filename, or when there are too many files to fit in the command buffer. Read [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for more discussion.

Comment: You're right: I don't know what will happen if there there are whitespaces in a filename. Thanks for pointing it out! I'll study your link and your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner will copy all files from the bar subfolder to the current directtory, with a name that start with `bar-`.

```
for i in bar/*; do cp "$i" "${i/\//-}"; done
```